# AutoFac register generic type explicitly

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

How do I tell register this generic repository? Each request should pass `ApplicationDbContext` as `TC`.

I have tried something like this:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<object, ApplicationDbContext>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>));
```

At the moment I have to register each one seperately which works but is tedious:

```
builder.RegisterType<Repository<AudioModel, ApplicationDbContext>>().As<IRepository<AudioModel>>();
```

Repository:

```
public class Repository<T, TC> : IRepository<T> 
        where T : class 
        where TC : DbContext
{
    private bool _disposed;

    protected TC Context { get; }

    public Repository()
    {

    }

    public Repository(TC context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class UploadService : IUploadService
{
    private readonly IRepository<AudioModel> _repository;

    public UploadService(IRepository<AudioModel> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `TC` should always be set to `ApplicationDbContext`, then it might be possible to make `TC` not a generic parameter (it doesn't need to be generic, it is always pretty specific).

If that is not an option, you could create a `ApplicationDbContextRepository`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext<T> : Repository<T, ApplicationDbContext>
{
}
```

and register this one as:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ApplicationDbContext<>)
       .As(typeof(IRepository<>));
```

But this depends on the rest of your application design.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
builder
    .RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)
    .As(typeof(IRepository<,>));
```

Autofac will register it correctly because the first type is the same in the implementation and the interface, and for the second type, it will simply pick any IRepository interface that has T as the first type and anything as the second.

Answer (score -1):

You can register your generic repository in this way:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>), typeof(IRepository<>));
```

You have to register to your AudioModel (I would use an interface instead object) and your db context.
Then you can resolve it.